# Eliminar espacio entre Body y el navegador

Tags: html, css

mi problema es el siguiente estoy desarrollando una página mobile y el body no me abarca toda la página... anexo el HTML y CSS, el efecto que necesito es que abarque todo el espacio disponible sin ese margen que se aprecia he intentado diferentes configuraciones y no sé que pueda ser.
He instalado la librería [normalize-css](/questions/tagged/normalize-css) y el problema persiste.

[image: body]

```css
  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    background-color: RGB(110, 116, 120);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .mcont {
    text-align: center;
  }
  h1 {
    background-color: RGB(184, 192, 200);
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mcont">
    <header>
      <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
      <form action="3-mobile.html" id="form">
        <label for="correo">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="correo" placeholder="Introduce tu correo">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Elimina margin y padding lol, tambien elmina margin y padding del elemento html si no te funciona con lo otro.

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes varias respuestas, sin embargo me gustaría comentarte lo siguiente:

En tu escenario estas con el problema a nivel de una *media query* por lo tanto es ahí donde debes aplicar a la etiqueta `body` el quitarle los márgenes; dado lo anterior debería verse así, haciendo uso de `margin: 0px;` además de quitarle tanto el `height` como el `width` de 100% que le has dado

```
@media only screen
  and (min-width: 320px) 
  and (max-width: 736px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
{ 


    body{
        background-color: RGB(110,116,120);
        margin: 0; --esta es la línea
    }

.mcont{
text-align: center;
}
 h1{
    background-color: RGB(184,192,200);
    color:black;
    }
```

> Es decir no apliques el `0px` al `margin` desde la etiqueta `body` principal sino desde aquella que declaras en la **media query**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar utilizando este código:

```
body{ margin-top: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes eliminar el margin y el padding del body. En este ejemplo se crea un **div**

```css
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#test{
height: 100px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funciona sin elementos si pongo un h1 por ejemplo pasa lo mismo que con mi proyecto :(

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar un "reset Css", añade la siguiente linea al inicio de tu hoja de estilo principal, espero te sirva. Saludos!!

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Si usas el selector `*` entonces le estas quitando el padding y el margin a todos los elementos eso incluye el input dentro de

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que existen diferentes formas de poder acomodar a una pantalla, intenta usar porcentajes o valores relativos

```
body {
    margin: 100%;
}
```

o intenta usar:

```
body {
    margin: 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, gracias por la aclaración BetaM.

Answer (score 0):

Esa última respuesta está mal. Si se pone: "margin: 100% 100% 100% 100%", entonces el body queda en 0% de ancho y 0% de alto. O sea: no se vería nada.

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es espacio para exponer dudas o comentarios